# Find the numbers (can’t use digits other than 1)

Tags: mathematics

Can you find two numbers composed only of ones which give the same result by addition and multiplication? Of course 1 and 11 are very near, but they will not quite do, because added they make 12, and multiplied they make only 11.

---

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

---

<sub>Source: “536 PUZZLES & CURIOUS PROBLEMS” by Henry Dudeney.</sub>

---

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, I think "can't use digits other than 1's" in the title is a more fair description than "composed of only ones".

Comment: @xnor I totally agree with you.  However when I post a puzzle that someone else created, I try as much as possible to use their original wording.  Thanks for your comment.  Have a nice day!

Comment: 200 reputaion or more...

Comment: Agree with the implication of Stevo's comments here. You encouraged for users with more than 200 reputation to refrain from answering, yet you quickly accepted an answer from a >200 rep user within 14 hours of posting (less than the standard guideline of having at least 24 hours before accepting an answer). 

Comment: @justhalf I wasn’t aware of the 24 hour guideline.  Thanks for letting me know about it.  Is there somewhere that I can read about PSE guidelines?  I want to act responsibly here.

Comment: That was my impression with StackExchange in general, and have seen that advice being thrown around a few times. But looking around again, now I think it's not really an official guidelines, although it's applied in many stacks (probably not Puzzling). For example [this RPG question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8618/26254), [this WorldBuilding meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8098/7723), [this Sci-Fi question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5065/55410), and [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28550/252363). So I suppose you're ok.

Comment: In general the idea is that it might encourage more users to give more answers (e.g., alternative explanation, possible second answer which wasn't considered, etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> We can rearrange $ab = a + b$ to get $a = \frac{b}{b - 1}$. Then we just plug values in for b. 1 clearly doesn't work, but 11 strikes gold:

> 11 * 1.1 = 11 + 1.1 = 12.1